# How to remove/rename the functions from tensorboard which were generated by TFRecordDataset parse_single_example

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a tf model which reads the data from `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`. So I have something like this:

```
keys_to_map = {
    "d": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    "s": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
}

def parser(record):
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_map)
    return parsed["d"], parsed["s"] 

tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files_train).shuffle(buffer_size=10000).map(parser).batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).repeat(-1).make_initializable_iterator()
```

when I visualize the graph, one part of it looks like this (*tf_data_structured_function_wrapper*):

[image]

Is there a way to rename/remove these functions into something more descriptive. Now it is clear what they mean and how they appeared in the code (in hindsight after I localized the problem), but when I had a huge graph it was very confusing.